# Populating list of items in Email body

Tags: c#

I am trying to populate list of items in my email body through my emial setup class.
 When i am trying to open email in my outlook, i can see just see one item where i am expecting list of items.

Below is my code :

```
 public class EmailSetup
{
    string toEmailSetup = string.Empty;
    string fromEmailSetup = string.Empty;
    string domainName = string.Empty;
    string emailServer = string.Empty;

    public void ApplicationFailedEmailSetup(List<string>ApplicationsInactive,DateTime dateRun)
    {
        toEmailSetup = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["To mailid"];
        fromEmailSetup = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From mailid"];
        domainName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain Name"];
        emailServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email Server"];
        try
        {
            var messager = new MailMessage();
            messager.To.Add(toEmailSetup);
            messager.Subject = "Applications Crashed/Closed";
            messager.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailSetup);
            try
            {
                messager.Body = "Following applications you are monitoring are closed are crashed:";
                **foreach (var item in ApplicationsInactive)
                {
                    messager.Body = item;
                }**  // Here i am trying to populate list of applications.
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
              throw;
            }

            var smtp = new SmtpClient(emailServer);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            try
            {
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Send(messager);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException
               ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in your loop is the problem:

```
messager.Body = item;
```

You're overwriting the `Body` property every time, so only the last item will be there following the loop.  You want to append instead:

```
messager.Body += item;
```

There are more ways to do this, of course, and this one is actually a bit sloppy.  Take a look at the `StringBuilder` class to create formatted strings and build your email body, then just set the email body to the `.ToString()` of the `StringBuilder` object.

---

Also, as a side note, this code is serving you no purpose:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

If you're not actually handling the exception in any meaningful way, why catch it at all?  The code is going to throw the exception, so just let it throw the exception.  There's absolutely no reason to catch it here, and this is just creating noise in the code.

Additionally, this one is also bad:

```
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException
       ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
}
```

You're suppressing the original exception and creating an entirely new one.  You're losing the stack trace and any other useful information from the original exception.  Is there a particular reason you want to convert `SmtpException`s to `ApplicationException`s?  At the very least, set the `InnerException` property of the `ApplicationException` to the `SmtpException` so that you don't completely lose that information.

But, more to the point, just as above, you're not actually handling the exception in any meaningful way.  No context is being added to it, no logging is being done, and you throw an exception anyway.  Again, this is just noise in the code.  There's no reason to catch an exception if you're not going to actually handle it.

Comment: Thanks For the reply and thanks for correcting my code.I am able to populate list of items but all are coming in just one line.

Comment: @62071072: This is where additional formatting comes into play.  How you approach that depends on whether or not your email is (or should be) HTML.  I don't see HTML in your code, so I'm assuming not.  But you can try, for starters, something as simple as: `messager.Body += item + Environment.NewLine;`

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is overwriting the body in each iteration, assigning it each item - resulting in the last item being the body.

You need to **append** to the body instead:

```
messager.Body = "Following applications you are monitoring are closed are crashed:";
messager.Body += string.Join(", ", ApplicationsInactive);
```

Note the **+=** operator instead of just **=**.

Also, you don't need loop at all - just use the handy `Join()` method of the `string` class to achieve same result with less and more readable code.

Comment: ApplicationsInactive is a list, i think i cant add list to the join() method

Comment: @62071072 You can starting with [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.100).aspx) - in case of older framework just change to `string.Join(", ", ApplicationsInactive.ToArray());`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But all th eitems are been populate djust in one line. Ex: Following applications you are monitoring are closed are crashed:abc,akdksa,aodjal

Comment: @62071072 so use `<br />` instead of comma: `string.Join("<br />", ApplicationsInactive);`